# Why we used only return statment in between if condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Why we only **return** in between if condition. Can anyone help me understand that condition?

```
  if (!name.trim()) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: `!name.trim()` - this condition will evaluate to true if `name` is an empty string. If the string is empty, then you don't want to do anything, so just `return` from the function. Basically, you want to execute your function beyond this condition only if the string is not empty.

Comment: How does the rest of the function look like? Are you familiar with the semantics of the `return` statement?

Answer (score 1):

We return in it because we will haven't to run code after the conđition. Increase performance and clean code

Comment: "increase performance" compared to what? Why would that be "clean code"?

Comment: 1. `we will haven't to run code after the conđition`

Answer (score 0):

The reason we just return is to terminate the execution of the function:

Here is an example with return:

```js
const test = Array(100).fill(1)

const getFifty = (arr) => {
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    sum += arr[i]
    if(sum >= 50){
     console.log("Sum is fifty at index" , i)
     return
    }
  }
  console.log("Sum is never fifty")
}

getFifty(test)
```

Here is an example without return:

```js
const test = Array(100).fill(1)

const getFifty = (arr) => {
  let sum = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    sum += arr[i]
    if(sum >= 50){
     console.log("Sum is fifty at index" , i)
    }
  }
  console.log("Sum is never fifty")
}

getFifty(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we use `return` in this situation, we have found the expected result and we do not need continue remain body of the function. Let's explain with an example. Assume that we would like find 75 from a loop with index and return the result. When we found the result, we do not need to execute the remain of functions body. This example also calculate the time between when you do not execute remain body of function, versus when you execute remain body of function. You will see that it effect on time of the execution, too.

```js
function testWithoutReturn() {
  let result = 0;
  let t1 =new Date();
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i == 75) {
      result = 75
      console.log("result founded but I will continue the loop needles!")
    }
    console.log(i);
  }
  let t2 = new Date();
  getTimeDif(t1,t2)
}
function getTimeDif(t1,t2){
  var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
  var sconds = dif / 1000;
  var result = Math.abs(sconds);;
  console.log(result)
}
testWithoutReturn()
```

```js
function testWithReturn() {
      let result = 0;
      let t1 =new Date();
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i == 75) {
          result = 75
          console.log("result founded and it doesn't need to continue loop")
          let t2 = new Date();
          getTimeDif(t1,t2)
          return;
        }
        console.log(i)
      }
    }
function getTimeDif(t1,t2){
  var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
  var sconds = dif / 1000;
  var result = Math.abs(sconds);;
  console.log(result)
}
    testWithReturn()
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, all "falsey" values evaluate to false. The examples given below are all considered "falsey":

- `false` - the false keyword
- `0` - the number zero
- `""` - the empty string
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

What `trim()` does is that it removes trailing and leading whitespaces from a string. So this code simply means "after removing trailing and leading whitespaces from the string, if the string is empty, then return nothing".

Comment: Boolean([]) = true

Comment: Also you forgot null and undefined on that list ...